# Find the rational values of $k$ for which $\sqrt[3]{\log_3(k)}=2^\frac23$

Tags: logarithms

Find the rational values of $k$ for which $$\sqrt[3]{\log_3(k)}=2^\frac23$$
I have tried to write it as $$\left(\log_3k\right)^\frac13=2^\frac23$$ but I don't know if this is helpful or not. Thank you!

Comment: How about starting by raising woth sides to the power of $3$? What do you get?

Comment: @Gary, thank you! We get $$\log_3(k)=4\iff k=3^4=81.$$

Comment: You are right. ${}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $2^{\frac{2}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{2^2}= \sqrt[3]{4}\implies \sqrt[3]{\log_3 k} = \sqrt[3]{4}$. Can you take it from here?